# when hover on mat-menu, icon which displays the menu disappears

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an angular component which have a `mat-tree` component.

Every tree node has action icon buttons which are displayed with hover on the node line.

When I click on the first icon, it displays a `mat-menu`. But since action icon buttons are displayed ONLY on mouse hover, when the hover is on the menu, all icons disappear.

What can I do to make all icons still visible when hovering on `mat-menu` ?

Stackblitz demo here : [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-haf1nr?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-nested-overview-example.html)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this line to the HTML:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'show-icons-and-menu': showIconsAndMenu && node === activeNode}">
```

right under this span tag:

```
<span class="hover-actions-menu">
```

And then added this to the SCSS:

```
.show-icons-and-menu {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

EDIT:

Add variable to store the active clicked node

*.ts

```
public activeNode = null;
```

Add click function which saved the active clicked node

*.html

```
<button mat-icon-button color="accent" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Example icon-button with a menu" (click)="activeNode = node">
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Almost that dude! thanks! But I have another display issue : when hovering on menu and going to other nodes: it displays every node icons.

Check this out : https://ibb.co/nBr3hxf

Comment: Glad I could help. The link is bad maybe try again in StackBlitz and I'll check it out

Comment: Oh I can see it now.

Comment: If you add this to the button that triggers the menu `(click)="activeNode = node"`. and at the top of your component class add: `activeNode = null`; and then change the ngClass expression to this:    `<div [ngClass]="{ 'show-icons-and-menu' : showIconsAndMenu && activeNode == node }"